# Do I lose my data if i factory reset my phone?

Tags: mobile-data

If I factory reset my phone, how long will it take for my data to set itself back up? And if it doesn't, have I lost my data?

Answer (score 1):

Factory reset will wipe everything in your device and your device will be as when you bought it. You should always backup your data before factory reset if you need it for after use.

Comment: And your data doesn't "set itself back up" again after that. That's something you have to take care for yourself. Even not if you've enabled Google's cloud backup – which at least up to Android 5.x includes parts at best.

Answer (score 0):

Your data does not set itself back up, factory resets remove everything on the phone memory so you should back up your data before you do a factory reset then copy it back to the phone after the reset is completed.